# in-memory sqlite in production with python

Tags: python, sqlite

I am creating a python system that needs to handle many files. Each of the file has more than 10 thousand lines of text data.

Because DB (like mysql) can not be used in that environment, when file is uploaded by a user, I think I will save all the data of the uploaded file in in-memory-SQLite so that I can use SQL to fetch specific data from there.

Then, when all operations by program are finished, save the processed data in a file. This is the file users will receive from the system.

But some websites say SQLite shouldn't be used in production. But in my case, I just save them temporarily in memory to use SQL for the data. Is there any problem for using SQLite in production even in this scenario?

Edit:
The data in in-memory-DB doesn't need to be shared between processes. It just creates tables, process data, then discard all data and tables after saving the processed data in file. I just think saving everything in list makes search difficult and slow. So using SQLite is still a problem?

Comment: Firefox is a good example of using sqlite pretty much ubiquitously

Comment: Take a look at pandas

Comment: You should also check if this can be done with python dictionaries in memory. Then time your solution and it might be good enough. Since you don't descibe your planned process in detail, it's impossible to ive you good advice here. Also, stack overflow is not for open questions, but to solve specific problems for which you give a reproducable example. This kind of question is more suited for reddit.com/r/learnpython

Comment: The data of each file has hierarchy (like parent-children), so I want to use SQL to fetch specific data. It might be possible with dict, but it would be difficult.

Answer (score 2):

`SQLite shouldn't be used in production` is not a one-for-all rule, it's more of a rule of thumb. Of course there are appliances where one could think of reasonable use of SQLite even in production environments.

However your case doesn't seem to be one of them. While SQLite supports multi-threaded and multi-process environments, it will lock all tables when it opens a write transaction. You need to ask yourself whether this is a problem for your particular case, but if you're uncertain go for "yes, it's a problem for me".

You'd be probably okay with in-memory structures alone, unless there are some details you haven't uncovered.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the specific context of your system, but if what you're looking for is a SQL database that is

- light
- Access is from a single process **and a single thread**.
- If the system crashes in the middle, you have a good way to recover from it (either backing up the last stable version of the database or just create it from scratch).

If you meet all these criteria, using SQLite is production is fine. OSX, for example, uses sqlite for a few purposes (e.g. .`/var/db/auth.db`).